# creating multiple directories based on value of variable

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

I have variable "one" which contains following

```
avi,mkw,dvd,cd
```

im trying to dynamicly create directories that would look like this

```
type-avi
type-mkw
type-dvd
type-cd
```

I have tried to achieve wanted result with following code

```
mkdir type-{"$one"}
```

but instead of creating 4 directories , it created one directory called

```
type-{avi,mkw,dvd,cd}
```

I suppose this is wrong method.. if so , how can i create dynamicly directories with "suffixes" stored in variabe?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4956584/sequences-expansion-and-variable-in-bash for why this didn't work. You get to loop manually for this.

Comment: indeed i could loop and just use the cut command to get the value , but how can i determine the length if the variable based on "," ? in my example 
avi,mkw,dvd,cd i would  need to return 4

Comment: `mkdir type-{$one}` works in `ksh` (ver 93+). Note, NO dbl-quotes on `$one` (One of the few times  you **don't** want to quote a variable, so it seems ;-) ) . Good luck.

Comment: @shellter Does that work if the elements of `$one` have spaces in their names or other globs?

Comment: Hm... actually that's an interesting trade-off here. Brace expansion means you can correctly glob individual entries at expansion time but an array means you need to move that to globbing to creation time.

Comment: @EtanReisner : `one="avi,mkw,dvd,cd,test space"; mkdir type-{$one}` did create the `type-test space` directory. (I'm surprised it did). What sort of glob are you thinking of? Wouldn't that attempt to expand to existing files in the current dir? Good luck to all.

Comment: @shellter Good to know for spaces (and somewhat surprising, I wonder what the evaluation order is there exactly). Yes, for `mkdir` here a glob doesn't make sense but it would for `type-{$one}/somedir` assuming there were many `type-foo*` directories to include for example. The question was mostly does the glob survive and expand correctly *after* the brace expansion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an array instead of your string variable for this.

```
IFS=, read -a onearr <<<"$one"
mkdir "${onearr[@]/#/type-}"
```

Or if you don't need the `$one` string in the first place just create the array manually.

```
onearr=(avi mkw dvd cd)
mkdir "${onearr[@]/#/type-}"
```

If you aren't worried about spaces or anything in the values in `$one` and can trust your input to be "safe" and not exploitative **and** can't use `read` then you *could* use this to create the array instead (but it is just flat out a worse soluton).

```
onearr=($(tr , ' ' <<<"$one"))
```

Comment: if i had variable which would be one="avi,mkw,dvd,cd" how could i create array from it ? ...im not sure if this question is for new topic or not :)

Comment: The first snippet here does exactly that. Notice that is uses `$one`.

Comment: is there any way how to do it without read? Im doing this exercises in order to prepare for school and we are not allowed to use read

Comment: thanks! :) one ast quetion why is the order mkdir "${onearr[@]/#/type-}" reversed? and what does  # in it mea?

Comment: See [Shell Parameter Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) in the bash manual.

Comment: `IFS=, a=($one)` splits the variable by comma, making each extension a value in an array. You can then step through them with `for d in "${a[@]}"; do mkdir type-$d; done`

Comment: @ghoti I know. That replaces a single call to `mkdir` with `N` calls to `mkdir` and "leaks" the new value of `IFS` to the environment though.

Comment: Hmm, I was thinking of setting IFS for the array assignment, but I realize you'd need `IFS=, declare -a a=($one)` for that. But I take your point on the single call to `mkdir` however. Of course, one could also just `eval mkdir type-{$one}`.  :-)

Comment: @ghoti That declare version doesn't work either. `$one` is still split by the current shell and not `declare`. You need `IFS=, declare -a a=(\$one)` for this and I'm not sure that doesn't open up other problems (and doesn't really improve anything over using `read` that I can think of so only makes sense in the context of that artificial restriction). I'll reserve comment about my thoughts on `eval`. =)

Comment: Huh, your `declare` option also doesn't work.  Looks like I am completely out to lunch, sorry for the misdirection.  +1 for getting this answer right in the first place.

Comment: @ghoti It worked for me (bash 3.2.25, 4.1.2 and 4.2.46 on CentOS 5, 6 and 7 respectively). But ideone (bash 4.3.33) agrees with you http://ideone.com/uOGXOp

Answer (score 0):

A way to do this without `read`ing into the shell, in a traditional tools pipeline approach:

```
echo "$one" |
tr ',' '\n' | 
sed "s/^/mkdir 'type-/; s/$/'/" |
sh -x
```

Your original attempt was very close. To make it work, you can use the shell `eval` command:

```
eval mkdir type-{$one}
```

or

```
echo mkdir type{"$one"} | bash
```

In either case, the effect causes `bash` to re-evaluate the line.

I personally would not recommend this approach for these reasons:

1. `eval` *can* be a security risk and is little used, maintainers will have to do a double-take.
2. Brace Expansion is a `bash`-type shell extension and while I love bash, I write all shell scripts to run with the POSIX `/bin/sh`.
3. These will not handle unusual characters in filenames, such as spaces.

The `eval` causes the shell to re-evaluate the string *after* the variable substition has been performed.  To gain more understanding on these topics, see "Brace Expansion" and also the `eval` command, both on the `bash` man page.

Comment: The final snippet is incorrect. You missed `echo`. And none of these will work with spaces in the contents of the components of `$one`. Not to mention that these all open up the potential for arbitrary code execution if you can't trust the value of `$one`.

Comment: @EtanReisner Typo, thanks, fixed.  Problems with the last two examples? More reasons not to use them. Answer updated, thanks!

Comment: @EtanReisner In the first example, what happens when there are "spaces in the contents of the components of $one"?  Did you try it?

Comment: Non-newline spaces in the first example are fine. Newlines break though. And it still allows for arbitrary code execution. Imagine `one` was `foo'; touch /tmp/broken; : '`?

Comment: @EtanReisner _Non-newline_ spaces? Sounds like back pedaling to me. Why not say "newlines"?  I understand what you mean by "arbitrary code execution."  The likelihood of newlines and arbitrary code execution varies widely by the context within which the code is used.

Comment: I failed to notice the single-quote wrapping when I wrote my original comment, mea culpa. If you want to call a valid sub-case of my original comment "back-pedalling" that's up to you. The newline case is valid. These options are all unsafe for arbitrary input and costlier then doing this in a safer way using `read` and `IFS`. And you don't know the full context for this code or who *else* will read it or where *else* the OP will use it. So while it may be "safe" enough here it has problems from an *objective* standpoint that I chose to mention.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95288/discussion-between-robertl-and-etan-reisner).